# How do I display only one author if he or she has several posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created my own custom post type (article). Now all authors of the articles should be shown on an overview page. If you click on the name, you will get to the respective author profile.

However, if an author has written, for example, three articles, he will be displayed three times on the overview page. Does anyone know how I can solve this problem? Thank you very much.

```
<?php get_header();

$args = (array(
    'post_type' => 'article',
    'orderby'   => 'name',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
));

$myquery = new WP_Query($args);
?>

<?php
// Start the loop.
if ($myquery->have_posts()) :
    while ($myquery->have_posts()) :
        $myquery->the_post();
        $img = get_the_author_meta('image-author');
        echo wp_get_attachment_image($img, 'image-author'); ?>
        <?php echo the_author_posts_link($args); ?>
    <?php
    endwhile;
endif;
?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Before you do anything in each iteration, check an array, for example `$exists` to see if it contains the author, if it does then you'll want to use `continue` to skip that iteration. At the end of each iteration, populate the `$exists` array with the author it just iterated through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try code below:

```
if ($myquery->have_posts()) :
    $authors_ids = [];
    while ($myquery->have_posts()) :
        $myquery->the_post();
        $img = get_the_author_meta('image-author');
        $author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');
        if (in_array($author_id, $authors_ids)) {
            continue;
        }
        $authors_ids[] = $author_id;
        echo wp_get_attachment_image($img, 'image-author');
        ?>
        <?php echo the_author_posts_link($args); ?>
    <?php
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: @Nelly click the tick next to the question to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

I have provided an example of what you can do below.

I can't give an exact fix for you because I don't know what your `WP_Query` class contains, but my example below should give you an understanding of what you need to do in order to achieve what you want.

```
// Set empty array that we will populate with authors.
$exists = [];

// Example list of authors.
$authors = ['Bob', 'Kirsty', 'Ralph', 'Penny', 'Kirsty', 'Bob', 'Alfie'];

// Loop through each author.
foreach($authors as $k => $author) {

    // We check to see if this author has already been mentioned, if it has, skip it.
    if(in_array($author, $exists)) continue;

    // Author has not previously been mentioned, so we echo this statement.
    echo 'The author for this iteration is ' . $author . '.<br />';

    // As this author hasn't been mentioned before, put them in the '$exists' array.
    $exists[] = $author;

}
```

Comment: Oh okay thanks. I tried it like this:

`$exists = [];
$authors = [get_the_author ($args)];

foreach($authors as $k => $author) {
if(in_array($author, $exists)) continue;
echo 'The author for this iteration is ' . $author . '.<br />';
 $exists[] = $author;
}
echo the_author_posts_link($author);`

But it doesn't work. I still get the author displayed several times.

Comment: @Nelly might be worth adding that code to your question under a heading called "What I've Tried" so we can see the code formatted properly.

Comment: What does `[get_the_author ($args)]` do?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I will bear this in mind in future. I'm still a newbie ;) But thank you so much for your help!